# CSS overflow: hidden using PIE.htc and position: fixed

Tags: internet-explorer, css, css3pie

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<style>
body { border: 0; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
#fixed { position: fixed; width: 100%; height: 40px; top: 0; left: 0; background: red; border-radius: 0 0 100% 100%; overflow: hidden; behavior: url(PIE.htc); }
#over { width: 1000px; height: 100%; margin: auto; background: green; }
</style>

<div id='fixed'><div id='over'></div></div>
```

What I'm trying to do is emulate the border-radius property on IE 7, IE 8 using PIE.htc.
There seems to be a problem with overflow: hidden when it comes to position: fixed elements.
My question is: Is there a way to make this work or, maybe, a workaround?

Thanks,
user1885099

Comment: the problem is that the overflow: hidden effect is not applied.